# Issue with using .remove() to take strings away from lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a big list of companies that I'm iterating through and I want the program to get rid of the individual company that I go through in the for loop. The issue is that I print the companies list each time in the for loop and it always prints the same list even after I do .remove().

Code:

```
for company in companies:
    test_times = test_times + 1
    companies.remove(company)
    print(f'Companies list: {companies}')
    print(f'Dictionary: {companies_sector}')
```

Example of output of printing companies:

```
['AA', 'AAAGY', 'AABC', 'AACB', 'AACE', 'AACPF', 'AAI1', 'AAIIQ', 'AAL', 'AAME', 'AANB', 'AAON']
```

Example of second output where company 'AA' should have been removed:

```
['AA', 'AAAGY', 'AABC', 'AACB', 'AACE', 'AACPF', 'AAI1', 'AAIIQ', 'AAL', 'AAME', 'AANB', 'AAON']
```

Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you are iterating over a list that keeps changing. Try it this way.

```
companies =  ['AA', 'AAAGY', 'AABC', 'AACB', 'AACE', 'AACPF', 'AAI1', 'AAIIQ', 'AAL', 'AAME', 'AANB', 'AAON']
companies_list =  companies [:]
for company in companies:
    companies_list.remove(company)
    print(f'Companies list: {companies_list}')
```

**Edit:**
In response to a question from the original poster in the comments, please run the code below and study the output. I think that will explain it better than I can.

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
for element in array :
    print (f'\nThe element about to be removed is "{element}".')
    print (f'It is at location {array.index (element)} in the array.')
    print (f'The array is now {array}.')
    input ('Press enter to continue.')
    array.remove (element)

print (f'\nThe array ended up {array}.')
```

Comment: `companies_list = companies.copy()` might be clearer than `[:]`

Comment: @bashBedlam the solution worked perfectly, I'm still unclear though as to why it didn't work originally. I would appreciate if you could give a little explanation so that I could understand better!

Comment: @LeMinaw with the solution above, the list that I have become disordered. Is there a way to make sure that, that doesn't better?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the list, and get a subset of the list, but the first element:

```py
for _ in range(len(companies)):
  element = companies[0]
  print(f'element: {element}')
  companies = companies[1:]
  print(f'companies: {companies}')
```